# Unable to access cookie value from onHeadersReceived

Tags: google-chrome-extension

From [this example](http://blob.tomerweller.com/cookie-interception-chrome-extension) I've use this code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    function (details) {
        details.responseHeaders.forEach(function(responseHeader){
             console.log(responseHeader.name + "===" + responseHeader.value);
            if (responseHeader.name.toLowerCase() === "set-cookie") {
                responseHeader.value = processSetCookieStr(responseHeader.value);
            }
        });
        return {
            responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders
        };
    }, {
        urls: ["*://*/*"]
    }, ['blocking','responseHeaders']
);
```

But I'm not able to see any cookie in the headers.

For `main_frame` type I've printed the values but cookie isn't there:

```
  Cache-Control===private 
  Content-Type===text/html; charset=utf-8
  Server===Microsoft-IIS/7.5 
  X-AspNet-Version===4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By===ASP.NET 
  Date===Sat, 29 Apr 2017 08:51:45 GMT
  Content-Length===29880
```

Though I'm able to fetch the desired cookie using `chrome.cookies.get`

Why am I unable to access cookie info in the `onHeadersReceived`?

Comment: Maybe cookies weren't sent in this particular response?  You can verify it in Fiddler or WireShark or similar tools.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes you're right. Cookies are sent only when session is changing. Shall I delete this question?

Answer (score 1):

You should add "extraHeaders" to the third parameter of the webRequest listener and it should be ['blocking','responseHeaders', 'extraHeaders'] for your example.

Starting from Chrome 72, the Set-Cookie response header is not provided and cannot be modified or removed without specifying 'extraHeaders' in opt_extraInfoSpec.

Refer https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/